# Can I use a firefox extension from Java?

Tags: java, firefox-addon

I want to be able to use existent firefox extensions in a java application. There are some extensions that make requests about the webpages I surf through and I want to avoid rewriting their code to get the functionality, but just (maybe) create an environment for them so that I can just "install" them in my app and be able to query their results. Is that possible? If not, would it be possible with minor changes to the plugin's code? If not would it be possible with XULRunner (I don't really know what that is, just heard it may help)? If not, what are the ways of doing such stuff (except rewriting all the code in another language)? Thanks

Comment: XUL Runner runs XUL files as standalone application in the operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embbed a XulRunner in a JavaApplication :

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaXPCOM/Embedding_Mozilla_in_a_Java_Application_using_JavaXPCOM

We are using an embedded XULRunner in an Eclipse RCP application but the latest correctly supported version of xulrunner with JAVAXPCOM is 1.8.1... (corresponding to the Gecko used in Firefox 2.0...).

It's a difficult way with an uncertain result...

Comment: and to answer the OP's question, porting the extension to run under the embedded XULRunner, once it's working, should be easy.